# Prevent scrolling a div with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking at this demo page:

http://www.ymc.ch/sandbox/hamburger/mobile-menu-demo.html

Which has this code behind it:

https://github.com/ymc-thzi/mobile-menu-hamburger

In general it works great but when the menu is open on my macbook I can use two fingers to scroll and move the white body div around. How could I prevent that using CSS?

Comment: I suspect you'll need JS for that. BTW, have you tried to play with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: @roko js is not needed, see my simple answer

Comment: The usual overflow in CSS doesn't work. I'm not even sure if this counts as "scrolling" per say but when I use two fingers on my track pad I can move the white content div around the screen (when the menu is open). Do other people see this issue as well?

Answer (score 14):

If you always want to prevent scrolling, you could use something like:

```
div {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Just be aware that any content that extends past the edge of the div will be `hidden` :)

Otherwise,  if you are just looking for a web mobile menu, check out [jQuery mobile](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/demos/panels/panel-nav-form.html).

Comment: Hidden will cut off content

Comment: Yeah, if the content extends out of the div, it will be cut off.

Comment: Good point, if he wants it cut off, I just assumed he was trying to kill the scrollbars and not hide content. Perhaps I misunderstood

Comment: That doesn't work. I'm not even sure if this counts as "scrolling" per say but when I use two fingers on my track pad I can move the white content div around the screen (when the menu is open). Do other people see this issue as well?

Comment: If you are just looking for a mobile menu, have you looked at the jquery mobile ones? http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/widgets/panels/

Comment: Mmmm... Interesting idea. Those seem to work pretty well. Ok, I'm going to have to try this out. Thanks @DylanWatson.

Comment: No worries! How did you end up going?

Comment: It will still scroll when user try to select content with keyboard. (By Mouse Dragging, followed by Shift+Right/Left)

Comment: Doesn't prevent mouse wheel scrolling.

Comment: Interestingly, focus can still scroll a `overview: hidden` div

Answer (score 1):

The scroll bars in the example URL are in the body, so you need to set the overflow property on the body to hidden when the menu is open and to auto when the menu is closed.

In the JavaScript file, you can add `jQuery(document.body).css('overflow', 'hidden')` in `jQuery("#hamburger").click` function and `jQuery(document.body).css('overflow', 'auto')` in the `jQuery("#contentLayer").click` function.

Comment: This causes the scroll bar to temporarily hide and show which is not an optimal user experience.